# Deserializing JSON

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I am having trouble deserializing the JSON request received.

Below is the JSON format I receive,

```
    {
        header:{
        worker count: 2},
        Worker:{
            name:emp1
        },
        Worker:{
            name:emp2
        },
        Worker:{
            name:emp3
        }
    }
```

With the below code, I tried to put them in the array -

```
string jsonstring = request.requestbody.tostring();
string regex = ',\\"([^\\"]+)\\"\\:+\\{'; // regex for ,"worker" :{
String resultStr = JSONreqstring.replaceFirst(regex, ',"Workers": [{'); //replace first occurance of "worker" with start of the workers array
String resultStr1 = resultStr.replace('"Worker":{', '{'); // remove subsequent worker and put them in the array
String resultStr2 = resultStr1.removeEnd('}'); 
resultStr3 = resultStr2 + ']}';
```

The resultstr3 would be -

```
{
    header:{
    worker count: 2},
    Workers:[{
        name:emp1
    },
    {
        name:emp2
    },
    {
        name:emp3
    }]
}
```

Then I am able to deserialize this, the problem is, if the json request has more number of records, i get the regex too complicated error
as salesforce has 1M character limit on the string for comparision.

Comment: please show what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a valid JSON, you might want to format it like this

```
   {
    "header": {
        "worker count": "2"
    },
    "Worker": [{
            "name": "emp1"
        },
        {
            "name": "emp2"
        },
        {
            "name": "emp3"
        }
    ]
}
```

array of worker Objects you put as value of "Worker" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is to use the [`JSONParser.readValueAs`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_JsonParser.htm)

This will avoid the headache of parsing a JSON node by node.

1/ 
First thing you need to do is to create an Apex POJO class with the same structure of the JSON.
Different tools you can use: [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) / [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) (This will generate a JAVA class but the code is very similar to Apex)

2/
Secondly, once you have the Apex Class created, for example `HeaderWorkerJSON` you can just in few lines of code, parse that JSON Text and create an object instance in memory (see code below)

```
String jsonString ='{YOUR_JSON}'
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonString);
HeaderWorkerJSON myParsedJSONObject = (HeaderWorkerJSON) parser.readValueAs(HeaderWorkerJSON.class);
```